# Account Settings not working

Tags: 18.04, settings

I've installed Wicd, and then removed it because I could not get the systray icon to appear.

Now, I can no longer access the account settings from the menu. By the Account Settings link, or via my username it is not working.

Any idea how I could go around this one?

Comment: Can you very clearly and precisely indicate how you try to get to the "account settings" (what do you mean with that?)

Comment: On the to right corner. the arrows pointing down, I click on my username and select Account Settings.
Or, still from the upper right corner, I click on the icon with the screwdriver to access the settings.
None is working. And I just realised that right click on the desktop to change the background does not work either.
I tried to installed the Desktop Preferences from the Repo, and when launching it, I got the message [Desktop manager is not active.]
Looks like following the instruction from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Comment: @vanadium 
Let me know if further info is required on this one.
From what I can see, anything which is control from the Settings is no longer working.
I was following the steps provided on the link posted above about Wicd, so uninstall and then reinstall the Network Manager.
Not sure how this could have broken so many things.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like it is resolved.
For some reason, after following the instruction to install, and then remove Wicd, I had lost the Gnome Control Center.

I've just reinstalled it from the Software Center, and I can now access all the settings.

Not sure how it is related to the install/remove of wicd though.